# Problem with solder-able Breadboard

Tags: circuit-design, signal, soldering, signal-processing

I'm having a very strange problem with a solder-able breadboard circuit I built. I'm trying to track the frequencies received from a speaker with a microphone.

[Microphone from Digikey](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/adafruit-industries-llc/2716/5604375)

I've built a regular breadboard circuit which transmits the frequencies I tell it to via PWM, and receives the raw voltages from the microphone. The graph of the frequencies received looks like this:
[image: Orange line: Frequency received by Mic. Blue line: Frequency transmitted by speaker]
The "gaps" in the frequency response I'm fairly certain come from cache misses from the microcontroller, which can be seen from sharp drops in the sampling rate at regular intervals (I've not included these as to try to keep this question concise).
The time domain response of the first window over which I performed a Fourier transform is shown below:[image]

Now, I've built the exact same circuit on a solder-able breadboard. I've checked the connections with a multimeter several times over, and also while the circuit is in operation, and everything is as it should be.

The solderable circuit's response looks like this:
[image]

And time domain response of a small window:
[image]

I worked to test parts of the circuit in isolation, and it seemed like the "breaking point" between working and not working was when I connected all pins on the solderboard to the MCU, *except* the ground which I connected to the negative power rail on a breadboard, which was *then* connected to the MCU. See below:
[image]

The frequency graph and time domain response of the microphone are below.
[image]
[image]

I should say that the fourier response is "cleanest" when I use the breadboard, and noisiest (in fact no peak at all at the required frequency) when I use the solderable breadboard.

It seems like the signal just gets attenuated as I move from breadboard connections to solder connections. My best guess as to what is happening is that the breadboard is somehow acting as a low-pass filter for the power supply pin, and without this the microphone's analog out pin doesn't produce good data (in the datasheet for the microphone, it says to use the cleanest PSU available, either 3.3 or 5V).

I don't have access to an oscilloscope, and I'm waiting on a separate PSU module/ PSU filter IC. However, I'm not even positive this is the problem. Please let me know if you have any suggestions or insights.

EDIT:
Here are my circuit diagrams (I apologize for hand-drawn).
[image]

*To be clear, the grounds are a common ground which is connected to the MCU (Beaglebone black industrial) ground*

This circuit works on a breadboard, but not when I solder it. The reason I *don't* think this is a soldering mistake (besides testing with a multimeter) is that the *soldered* circuit works in this configuration:
[image]
Where the breadboard ground rail is used as an "intermediate" between the soldered board and the MCU ground. I know this doesn't make sense (or at least it doesn't to me), and I appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: Do you have a multimeter?

Comment: Hunt down your ground loops if any.  Much easier to accidentally make some without a dedicated rail.  Stray/accidental solder is also problematic.  Use meter and test for extra connections, even if temporary where there should be none.

Comment: You most likely have power supply noise on your microphone ground reference. Draw a schematic so we don;t have to trace your wires.

Comment: The majority of your solder joints are cold. Cover them with flux and heat them up again. When soldering these, try to heat up the copper of the board for a while first, before moving the iron to the joint. The board will take much longer to heat than the component legs.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Yes, I've checked all the joints repeatedly and also the voltages in operation and everything is as it should be.

Comment: @Lundin I think its highly unlikely the joints are cold, as I've checked them all with a multi-meter. Additionally, the circuit works (sound comes out of the speaker, the microphone reads voltages) so long as its not connected directly to the MCU. I'll recheck everything however.

Comment: Measure Vdd and ADC DC voltages (to local ground) at mic board and MCU board, with speaker sounding.

Comment: @davedawave Several are clearly cold, as anyone with basic soldering training can tell by just looking at your picture. You can't tell if joints are cold with a multimeter. The very definition of a cold joint is: it works for now, until it doesn't any longer. Overall you should never be looking at a blob of solder or it has not wetted properly. For plated through hole vias, it should ideally also have wetted at the opposite side of the board.

Comment: @Lundin I didn't realize a joint could be cold if the multi-meter showed a connection. I followed your suggestion and re-soldered, and got rid of the excess blobs. I'm still having the same issue however. The voltages are correct in operation as well.

Comment: @davedawave What happens is that if both metal surfaces wasn't heated properly, they are not actually joined by solder and there could still be an air gap, or the surfaces just stick together because there's a slight "glue" effect from the solder or by capillary force.

Answer (score 0):

Cache misses? The ADC runs on the DMA, and if it doesn’t – change it so it would. It should be paced by a timer. No per-sample interrupts.

What exactly is the MCU and the board you’re using? This should be an easy thing to do, the problems likely have nothing to do with any caches. Not for audio frequencies anyway. You could sample audio using interrupts on an MC68000 without any problems. I highly doubt a modern ARM MCU will have much problem of the nature you describe.

Comment: The code is a bit hack-y at the moment, and I'm currently using the Adafruit BBIO.ADC library for the Beaglebone black industrial board. I will eventually implement DMA, but I believe this is a hardware issue, not software. Again, the pipeline works with a breadboard but not when I solder it. You are correct in saying it likely has nothing to do with cache misses- I was trying to explain the points where the orange (measured) frequency did not match up to the speaker (blue) frequency.